# Admob Ads are not showing on Real Devices

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

Test Ad ids are working whenever tried with real ad mob ids ads are not visible

Answer (score 0):

Here check your adView listener

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
}

@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
     Log.d("ADMOB" , ""+errorCode);
}

@Override
public void onAdOpened() {
    // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
    // covers the screen.
}

@Override
public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
}

@Override
public void onAdClosed() {
    // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
    // to the app after tapping on an ad.
}
});
```

if error code is 3 that means there is no ads to serve you but your implementation is right.

Comment: i got error code 3 tqs brother for your reply, any suggestions to get ads????

Comment: when ads are abailable it will comes automatically don't worry. If you think this answer is helpful for you please accept my answer by pressing up button in side.